How do I fix the error 'Undefined array key' in this php code?
I'm trying to test a simple php / mySQL database setup where a page connects to data in a database table and updates the information in that table. I've never had any problems in the past with this code but since installing MAMP and php version 8.2.20 on my computer the pages do not work and I'm presented with a slew of errors. Here it is saying the array keys are undefined for each of the column headings of the table.
<?php

    // servername => localhost
    // username => root
    // password => Graplan4
    // database name => netpark-floorplans
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Graplan4", "netpark-floorplans");
      
    // Check connection
    if($conn === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " 
            . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    
    // Taking all 6 values from the form data(input)
    $record = $_REQUEST['record'];
    $room_number =  $_REQUEST['room_number'];
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $job_title =  $_REQUEST['job_title'];
    $description = $_REQUEST['description'];
    $research_group = $_REQUEST['research_group'];
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM roomdetails WHERE record = '$record'";
    
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows < 1) {
    
    // Performing insert query execution
    // here our table name is college
    $sql = "INSERT INTO roomdetails VALUES ('$record','$room_number','$name','$job_title','$description','$research_group')";
    }
    else 
    $sql = "UPDATE `roomdetails` SET `record`='$record', `room_number`='$room_number',`name`='$name',`job_title`='$job_title',`description`='$description',`research_group`='$research_group' WHERE record = '$record'";
    
    
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
        echo "<h3>Room information updated successfully</h3><p style='font-size: 14pt;'>
        <a href='floorplan.php' onClick='javascript:opener.location.reload(); window.close();'>Return to Floorplan</a></p>"; 

        echo nl2br("\n $room_number\n $name\n "
            . "$job_title\n $description\n $research_group");
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Hush! Sorry $sql. " 
            . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
      
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>

I expected this page to connect to the database, updating the room information values for the selected record in the table accordingly. However instead I just get these errors:
Warning: Undefined array key "record" in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Netpark/insert.php on line 25
Warning: Undefined array key "room_number" in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Netpark/insert.php on line 26
Warning: Undefined array key "name" in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Netpark/insert.php on line 27
Warning: Undefined array key "job_title" in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Netpark/insert.php on line 28
Warning: Undefined array key "description" in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Netpark/insert.php on line 29
Warning: Undefined array key "research_group" in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Netpark/insert.php on line 30
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'record' at row 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Netpark/insert.php:46 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Netpark/insert.php(46): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO roo...') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Netpark/insert.php on line 46

You shouldn't call this code unconditionally, but only on a POST request. Also change $_REQUEST to $_POST. Also make sure the HTML form is OK
